# Am I the only one getting addicted to this site? How do you manage time doing other things?

Tags: discussion

On one hand, this site is a blessing because we can all learn a lot quickly looking at some technical questions/topics being discussed.  On the other hand, this could also be addictive.  Maybe set aside 1/2 hour every day for this?  What time management strategies have you all used and can you suggest?

Comment: No, you are not the only one :-)

Comment: It's *very* addictive. I remember someone just staying off  it a bit because of that. Perhaps I should do that too!

Comment: From Wikipedia article on [Mathoveflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathOverflow), which is very similar site: Jordan Ellenberg comments that the website "offers a constantly changing array of new questions" and is "addictive" in a "particularly pure form", as he compares it to the Polymath Project. Th article gives [this blog](http://quomodocumque.wordpress.com/2009/10/17/why-math-overflow-works-and-why-it-might-not/) as the source of this quote.

Comment: Very willing to join an MSE-holics non-anonymous support group, if one exists somewhere? Occasionally I get the feeling that it is under control, but ... let's check the site one more time before going to bed. Should I get enrolled in a 12-step program or something?

Comment: Not sure that this really helps, but there also is [productivity.SE](http://productivity.stackexchange.com/) - a site about personal productivity. (It is in beta.)

Comment: I like to use [ProcrastiTracker](http://procrastitracker.com/) to monitor my habits. But Leechblock is great too, thx David.

Comment: Quit your job.  Sell your house.  Hang out all day in an internet cafe, and stay on stackexchange full time.  No need for sleeping!

Comment: This is not a problem.  It is, simply put, normal.

Comment: hahhahhaha... +1, to the group of MSEholics i mean.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I guess productivity.se was insufficiently productive. Clicking on your link took me to https://stackexchange.com/site-not-found

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it was closed, see here: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity One of the things which remained from that site is [this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/598/2011/6/22).

Answer (score 21):

I recommend Leechblock; this is a browser add-on for Firefox that blocks certain sites during certain times of the day.

To avoid future link root, no link is provided. It is available from Mozilla's site. The easiest way to find it is likely to search for the name.

Presumably similar things exist for other browsers.

Comment: Does that really work for you? Do you consider yourself addicted to MSE?

Comment: @lhf I think the current state of D.S.'s profile answers your question. :)

Comment: It was signaled that the original link was broken, thus I took the opportunity to expand a bit. Obviously feel free to remove or correct.