# Is it possible to temporarily disable my account on MSE?

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, account-suspension

I have been obsessively checking MSE in the past month. In fact, I have learned a lot from this community just in the last weeks that I have been active here (I registered in April, but I never really used this website until this November). However, since I'm a student myself and my final exams are near, I'm afraid that I'll have to leave again for a month or so.

I want to know whether it is possible to temporarily disable my account on MSE or not? I don't want to delete my account. I just think I can focus on my exams better without this "answer the questions on MSE" obsession. And if it's not possible, why is not possible? Is it possible to change the rules in near future to allow this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably this can be done by mods, see [this conversation in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34686801#34686801). A related post on this meta: [Am I the only one getting addicted to this site? How do you manage time doing other things?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3850) And on meta.SE:
[Can an account be self-suspended?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/106604) and [“Ban myself” button in user profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32299).

Comment: @MartinSleziak: How can I find a mod? I also want it to appear as it was not forced on me. Like I was banned because I got into a fight with someone or something. xD

Comment: Are you a maths student? I used to have the same issue. My method is to convince myself that solving exam practice exercise is also interesting.

Comment: @AlexVong: Yes, I am. I'm already behind my study schedule for my own exams and in fact, I am answering questions on MSE that are irrelevant to the courses I have this semester. :( MSE is indeed addictive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no dedicated feature for this on SE, but there are varied general purpose tools to block you from using certain sites.

Yet, if you want, we can just suspend you for the period of time you request. Just state for how long.

You can edit your about me first saying that you were suspended on your request to avoid the misconception that you were actually suspended.

If you want to keep using chat, change your parent user on the chat profile to another one.

Generally, to contact a moderator use a flag (flag, other) on one of your posts or ask in [Math Mods' office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office) in chat.

Comment: Just curious why kind of reasons would be displayed in this situation? to cool down?

Comment: Sounds like a good option. So, suppose that I asked moderators to ban me for like 30 days. Will I be able to ask moderators to lift the ban if I changed my mind earlier than that?

Comment: @stressedout-gone- Yes. If you follow the advice on changing your parent user in chat, you could ask in chat. But, even if not you could reply to the moderator message you will necessarily receive with the suspension (note though that you can only reply once to that message). That said, it is not feasible that moderators cater to numerous wishes of suspensions and unsuspensions. Thus, please, try to make up your mind as much as possible and minimize any back-and-forth.

Comment: @JohnMa yes, likely this, as it seems most generic.