# How much time a day is healthy to spend on MSE?

Tags: discussion

I'm being relatively active in MSE approximately a month ago.

I've spent a lot of time between trying to answer questions, editing, viewing the questions, even reading some old posts here in Meta, the discussions and everything.

As we all know, it's an addictive site (and has a lot of pros, for sure) but lately I feel that I've spent a lot of the day here, even in hours when I probably should be sleeping.

I want to ask to the community, how much time a day do you think is healthy to be here, or how many hours do you spend here? Can you give me some advices to manage this activity in a healthy way? I'll read you carefully, thank you!

Comment: Between 18 to 23 hours. Anything less is ridiculous.

Comment: none. but we use it anyways.

Comment: If you find yourself asking this question I think you know the answer already (in comparison to your current ours). Welcome to the club anyway.

Comment: It's a problem when it begins to interfere with your daily activities. I remember a time when I was spending nearly every waking hour on the site, basically eating deeply into my free time. Luckily life happened and broke that habit harshly. If the site is interfering with your sleep schedule, as you seem to suggest, no doubt it's otherwise eating into your life and time in other harmful ways. It might be best to back off a bit. (But as Jyrki noted: if you feel the need to ask this question, you probably already feel that this is a problem without our affirmations.)

Comment: See also: [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3850/am-i-the-only-one-getting-addicted-to-this-site-how-do-you-manage-time-doing-ot?noredirect=1&lq=1).