# How many hours has a user been on math.stack?

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, statistics, timeline

In this question, [How much time a day is healthy to spend on MSE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31199/how-much-time-a-day-is-healthy-to-spend-on-mse) OP asked this

"how many hours do you spend here?"

And made me think that if

Is it possible to know the total of hours that a user has spent on math.stack ?

I mean online, not since the time they created their account.

Thank you

Comment: This post on [meta.se] seems related: [To estimate how much time I've spent on SE, what tools are available to help, or at least how can I “vacuum up” all of my timestamps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/318118)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks

Comment: enough to have my blood boiling and to delete my account for a second time ... mostly due to just 2 or 3 users.... that frankly should confine themselves to mathoverflow if they want advanced explanations.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee ?

Comment: "enough to have my blood boiling and to delete my account for a second time ... mostly due to just 2 or 3 users.... " ? what are you talking about about?

Comment: within 24 hours I will no longer have an account here...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Why?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I don't know what happened, I don't know what the trouble with the 2-3 users was; but from what you said, you seem upset. It's _absolutely_ not recommended to take decisions (especially irreversible ones!) when one is upset. I'd suggest you to take some time off, so that you can think clearly and so make good choices.

Comment: No, there is no way for normal users to know. Even mods don't have an easy way to know. That aside, the stats may not be reliable at all since some users (e.g. me) leave the SE tab open 24 hours... while they're doing other things.